# Append multiple csv files into one file using R

Tags: r

I Have multiple csv files that i have already read into R. Now I want to append all these into one file. I tried few things but getting different errors. Can anyone please help me with this?

TRY 1:

```
mydata <- rbind(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8)
```

WHERE XI,X2....X8 Are the  CSV files I read into R, error I am getting is

ERROR 1 :In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

TRY 2: Then I try this in another way :

```
mydata1<- c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8)
> mydata2 <- do.call('rbind',lapply(mydata1,read.table,header=T))
```

Error 2: in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection

can anyone please help me know what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Does all the files have same columns in same order and are there equal number of columns? If unequal, then different solution.

Comment: @Sowmta S. Manian yes all columns have same order and have same number of columns only different number of rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sample CSV Files**

**Note**
CSV files to be merged here have
- equal number of columns
- same column names
- same order of columns
- number of rows can be different

1st csv file `abc.csv`

```
A,B,C,D
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,5
3,4,5,6
1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2
44,44,44,44
4,4,4,4
4,4,4,4
33,33,33,33
11,1,11,1
```

2nd csv file `pqr.csv`

```
 A,B,C,D
 1,2,3,40
 2,3,4,50
 3,4,50,60
 4,4,4,4
 5,5,5,5
 6,6,6,6
```

---

**List FILENAMES of CSV Files**

**Note**
The path below `E:/MergeCSV/` has just the files to be merged. No other csv files. So in this path, there are only two csv files, `abc.csv` and `pqr.csv`

```
## List filenames to be merged. 
filenames <- list.files(path="E:/MergeCSV/",pattern="*.csv")

## Print filenames to be merged
print(filenames)
## [1] "abc.csv" "pqr.csv"
```

**FULL PATH to CSV Files**

```
## Full path to csv filenames
fullpath=file.path("E:/MergeCSV",filenames)

## Print Full Path to the files
print(fullpath)
## [1] "E:/MergeCSV/abc.csv" "E:/MergeCSV/pqr.csv"
```

**MERGE CSV Files**

```
## Merge listed files from the path above
dataset <- do.call("rbind",lapply(filenames,FUN=function(files){ read.csv(files)}))

## Print the merged csv dataset, if its large use `head()` function to get glimpse of merged dataset
dataset
#     A  B  C  D
# 1   1  2  3  4
# 2   2  3  4  5
# 3   3  4  5  6
# 4   1  1  1  1
# 5   2  2  2  2
# 6  44 44 44 44
# 7   4  4  4  4
# 8   4  4  4  4
# 9  33 33 33 33
# 10 11  1 11  1
# 11  1  2  3 40
# 12  2  3  4 50
# 13  3  4 50 60
# 14  4  4  4  4
# 15  5  5  5  5
# 16  6  6  6  6

head(dataset)
#    A  B  C  D
# 1  1  2  3  4
# 2  2  3  4  5
# 3  3  4  5  6
# 4  1  1  1  1
# 5  2  2  2  2
# 6 44 44 44 44

## Print dimension of merged dataset
dim(dataset)
## [1] 16  4
```

Comment: It is still giving me error filenames <-list.files(path="c:\\users\\yz\\Desktop\\test\\",pattern=".*csv")
> fullpath=file.path("c:\\users\\yz\\Desktop\\test",filenames)
> datasetsim <- do.call("rbind",lapply(filenames,FUN=function(files){read.csv(files)})) Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'data1.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: try putting just "*.csv" or "csv" instead of ".*csv" in list.files() for pattern argument value.

Comment: If not working, Ill delete it as I have not tested it yet. Need to install R to test. If helps..then great.

Comment: ..Something is wrong with ##Merging listed files from path above..Giving me same error

Comment: Hope your working directory is not set to R's bin folder or something..bcoz tbat usually throws Error in File "rr" thing. Set that folder with csv files as your working directory in new session.

Comment: I have tried it, updated my answer. It is working now on my side.

Answer (score 6):

How to import all files from a single folder at once and bind by row (e.g., same format for each file.)

```
library(tidyverse)

 list.files(path = "location_of/data/folder_you_want/",
              pattern="*.csv", 
              full.names = T) %>% 
    map_df(~read_csv(.))
```

If there is a file that you want to exclude then

```
list.files(path = "location_of/data/folder_you_want/",
              pattern="*.csv", 
              full.names = T) %>% 
    .[ !grepl("data/folder/name_of_file_to_remove.csv",  .) ] %>%
    map_df(~read_csv(.))
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer above generates the error shown in the comments because the `do.call` requires the `"fullpath"` parameter. Use the code as shown to use in the directory of your choice:

```
dataset <- do.call("rbind",lapply(fullpath,FUN=function(files){ read.csv(files)}))
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your code, now, corrects the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of lapply(), and do.call().

```
## cd to the csv directory
setwd("mycsvs")

## read in csvs
csvList <- lapply(list.files("./"), read.csv, stringsAsFactors = F)

## bind them all with do.call
csv <- do.call(rbind, csvList)
```

You can also use `fread()` function from the **data.table** package and `rbindlist()` instead for a performance boost.